# TomEE + Spring Framework + JNDI Lookup Failures

Tags: spring, apache-tomee

I have a simple Spring Framework (4.3.16.RELEASE) ear file deployed to TomEE (tomee-plume-8.0.0-M2) using Zulu Java (zulu8.36.0.1-ca-jdk8.0.202-macosx_x64).

I getting errors injecting a data source via JNDI Lookup.   My TomEE instance has the following resource in server.xml:

```html
     <Resource
     auth="Container"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     name="jdbc/my/DataSource"
     password="1234"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@database.local:1521/db"
     username="admin" />
```

In my application ear I have the following in my web.xml file:

```html
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/r/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My applicationContext.xml that lookups the JNDI resource:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
 
 <!-- Configures support for @Controllers  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="local.gerb" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

 <jee:jndi-lookup id="writeDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/my/DataSource" resource-ref="true"/>

 <bean id="helloWorld" class="local.gerb.HelloWorldImpl" />
    
</beans>
```

However, when I deploy the application I get the following error in the log file:

```
    CreationException: Error creating bean with name 'writeDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/my/DataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    04-Mar-2019 12:43:33.610 SEVERE [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'writeDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/my/DataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
```

I do see the jdbc/my/DataSource being created in TomEE:

```
    04-Mar-2019 12:43:32.113 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'jdbc/my/DataSource' of type 'javax.sql.DataSource'.
    04-Mar-2019 12:43:32.113 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=jdbc/my/DataSource)
```

So I believe I created the Resource correctly in TomEE but for some reason, spring framework is unable to correctly inject the resource.

I do have the full source pushed to my github repo: https://github.com/jstralko/tomee-poc/tree/master/SpringExamples  in case you want to look at everything, I kept it as minimal as possible to help debug this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly, apparently, once I moved the Resource into context.xml from server.xml; I was able to successfully inject a JDBC resource.